# Load jquery behaviors on dynamically created object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements structured like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="tag_name">Tag Name</div>
        <div class="delete">X</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!-- and so long... -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

In jQuery I have a `$('.delete').click()` function on `$(document).ready()` that removes the parent `<li>` element. I also have a function for adding a `<li>` element and on those elements the remove function does not work. How do I activate my javascript (jQuery) functions on a dynamically generated element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using delegation:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.delete', function(){
   //...
});
```

Set it once UL is available in the DOM, or just wrap it inside document ready handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the importance of [**JQuery Delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now **or are added in the future**.

In your case:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.delete', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```